# How do I add an onclick event to html tags without id's using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried doing this but it didn't seem to work:

```
 window.onload = initAll;


    function initAll(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('a').onclick = clickHandler;
     }

    function clickHandler(){
        if(this.toString().indexOf("localhost") < 0) {
            confirmation = confirm("You are now leaving http://soso.com.  Please click 'ok' to continue to this site, or 'cancel' to stay in http://soso.com");
                if (confirmation == false){
                    return false;
                }

        }

    }
```

I know I can getElementById and that works, but it doesnt work this way.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does 'document.getElementsByTagName' return an array? You may need to loop through that returned array and assign the handler?

Comment: JQuery was designed specifically for this sort of work. Can you use Jquery?

Comment: I was considering jquery to insert the onclick handler if there wasnt a simpler fix, yes.

Answer (score 6):

*document.getElementsByTagName('a')* returns a NodeList of DOM Elements. So for starters, you will have to iterate over them and attach a handler to each like this :

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for( var i=0,il = links.length; i< il; i ++ ){
 links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

If there are many elements, I suggest you read about [event delegation](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/04/event-delegation-with-javascript/) and assign just one handler for everything.

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after the condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
function initAll() 
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); // returns an array

    // add the handler to each element
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < elements.length; ++n)
        elements[n].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

Comment: Replace with `int` with `var`, that is not valid Javascript.

Comment: int n; :O :O . There is no int in JavaScript.

Comment: Also, you might wanna compute that length property once. It might cause serious issues in this case as getElementsByTagName returns a live list of elements.

Comment: @Rajat the list is only going to change if OP specifically changes it, in which case he probably wants an up-to-date length reference. however your suggestion is a good one for optimizing a fixed-length list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over all of the elements returned by `document.getElementsByTagName`

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i = links.length;
while ( i-- ) {
    links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
// ... rest of your code ...
```

Comment: your condition is wrong. should be `i > 0`. also you can combine your decrement and condition to get `while ( i-- )`.

Comment: What about `while( i-- ) { links[i].onclick = clickHandler; }`?

Comment: @lincolnk @palswim -- good points ... updated to be slightly more sensible (and work ... you know, while we're fixing things) :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`. You cannot assign an event handler via the `onclick` property on a `NodeList`, only a single `DOMElement`.

Try:

```
 var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = clickHandler;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using JQuery. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(function(){$('a').click(clickHandler);});
```

Comment: While jQuery *does* make working with the DOM easier, including 24KB of code (minified and gzipped) on the page when 125 **characters** does the trick is rather overkill. ;-)

Comment: @Sean: 125 unicode characters will take 4 KB of code. Including all that code inline on your document (which is probably what he's doing) adds up to 24KB quickly over a number of page requests. If you use Google's hosted copy, you can leverage their fast, distributed servers to serve up JQuery quickly, with a high likelihood that the user will have it cached already anyway. It also means you can use JQuery anywhere else in your application to create concise, cross-browser-compatible code. Unless this is the only place he's going to use javascript, I'd say it's a no-brainer.

Comment: "125 unicode characters will take 4 KB of code." You sure about that? In UTF-8 that would be 125 bytes, no? And in UTF-32, at 125 * 4 or 500 bytes.